# Git status reports deleted files which still exist

Tags: git

My Git status is showing all files `deleted` in my working tree which is incorrect, they are still there.

To resolve it, I should execute `git reset --hard` which reset all my modifications to other files.

Any idea how to solve it or how did it happen?

`git status` output:

```
On branch develop
Your branch is behind 'origin/develop' by 15 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.

Changes to be committed:
(use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

deleted:    .gitignore
deleted:    v3/.gitignore
deleted:    v3/index-test.php
deleted:    v3/index.php
deleted:    v3/protected/.gitignore
deleted:    v3/protected/.htaccess
deleted:    v3/protected/Gruntfile.js
```

Edit: The above is not the complete `git status` output. 
Those files that I was working on are not staged for deletion.

Comment: It's helpful to show the output here, even if it's trimmed a bit and paths are obscured.  Also, it's helpful to talk about what you did leading up to this issue.  It sounds to me like the files are staged for delete in the index, but present in the working copy.  But I can't really tell from your description.

Comment: yes, they are staged for delete. I'll add the `git status` output to the question.

Comment: Is that the entirety of your `git status` output, or did you snip it?  The reason I ask is because you say you have modifications to other files, and from your `git status` output, it doesn't appear that way.

Comment: That's not the entire status output, those files that I was working on are not staged

Answer (score 6):

If the only issue is that the some files have been removed from the index, but are still in the working tree, then all you need to do is:

```
git reset
```

By default, `git reset` defaults to mixed mode which does this:

> --mixed
>
> Resets the index but not the working tree (i.e., the changed files are preserved but not marked for
>       commit) and reports what has not been updated. This is the default action.

So it will leave your changes intact but unstage everything.  If you find that the files *are* actually missing, then you'll need to check them out to restore them:

```
git checkout -- path/to/file/or/dir
```

You could parse the short form of `git status` using `cut` and `xargs` to help do this if you have lots of files.  I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader though, since you're claiming that all the files are there.

Comment: ```git reset```worked for me after cloud sync seemingly messed up the folder. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

if you deleted a file from local disk using

```
rm file.name
```

and if `file.name` was already checked into git. Then you should actually issue this command

```
git rm file.name
```

to tell git that you don't want it to track that file anymore

Answer (score 1):

```
  git co my_annoying_file
  git rm my_annoying_file
  git commit -m "removing annoying file"
```

now they are truly deleted from git tracking

...also `git reset --hard` may be to brittle for this scenario, consider `git reset HEAD my_annoying_file`

Comment: thanks. but it's not just a single annoying file.. it's the whole working tree.

Comment: same should apply to folder, but it sounds like you have git repository inside git repository. Try to check if you have folder called `.git` in that folder that causing an issue

Comment: there is a .git directory which belongs to git-flow, will double check if that's the source of problem. thanks.